# Rails API - Error with Admin authorizable in production [heroku]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, authorization, token

I build a rails API, everything works well in development. I can access to my endpoints, logs and admin work too.

But on heroku I have this error in my logs :

[image]

Here is my module where the error seems to be :

[image]

Do you have any clue ?

Thanks for your help and enjoy your day !

Answer (score 1):

```
class NotPermittedException < StandardError; end
```

this line was missing above my module :)